# Creating a Column in Excel Based on Percentages

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm simulating a dataset in Excel and want to create a column that only takes the values Yes or No. I want to make it so that 20% of the cells in that column are No and the remaining 80% are Yes. I want the No's to be randomly dispersed through the column, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Office 365 you could use `=CHOOSE(IF(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(100),RANDARRAY(100))<=20,1,2),"No","Yes")`

It creates a sequence of 100 numbers and randomly sorts them. If the value is 20 or less it shows (chooses) `No`, else `Yes`.

You can make it dynamic by having `100` replaced by `ROWS([your range])` and `20` by `ROWS([your range])*0.2`

Edit: CHOOSE is not necessary, IF already takes care of it: `=IF(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(100),RANDARRAY(100))<=20,"No","Yes")`
Thanks to Scott Craner

Answer (score -1):

Please share your work and so that we can guide you in the right path.
To get started see =CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"Yes","No"), this might give you some ideas.